# Applescript - duplicate file to folder

Tags: applescript, finder

(noob / novice) here I have done many searches online but cannot get this to work

I am trying to get a file duplicated from a pre-determined location into a newly created folder from within the script.

The script basically asks for a few bits of info and creates a folder structure using the info and a predefined set of folder within. from there I would want it to copy some template files (.psd .fcpbundle etc) from a template folder on the HDD.

my code is as follows now it all works up until it tries to copy the file

```
tell application "Finder"
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the wedding date" default answer "YYYY/MM/DD") --Asks for date of wedding
set DT to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the couples name" default answer "Bride & Groom + Surname") --Asks for couples name
set Wedding to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the type of day" default answer "Wedding") --Asks for type of day, Wedding, Party, etc
--Creates directory with info from above
set loc to choose folder "Please choose where you would like to save the files" --Loc = Location of where directory will be placed
set newfoldername to JobName & " - " & DT & " - " & Wedding --Adds Date, Couples name and event type to make directory name
--Creates parent directory
set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername} --Directory name defined
set audio to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Audio"} --creates Audio Directory
set doc to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Documents"} --creates Documents Directory
set exports to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Exports"} --creates Exports Directory
set fpcx to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"FCPX Library"} --creates FCPX Directory
set filmposter to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Film Poster"} --creates FilmPoster Directory
set finaldel to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Final Delivery"} --creates Final Delivery Directory
set images to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Images"} --creates Images Directory
set rawcards to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"RAW Cards"} --creates RAW Cards Directory
set xml to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"XML"} --creates XML Directory
--Creates sub-folders
set submusic to make new folder at audio with properties {name:"Music"} --creates Music in Audio Directory
set subrawaudio to make new folder at audio with properties {name:"RAW Audio Cards"} --creates RAW Audio Cards in Audio Directory
set subdvd to make new folder at finaldel with properties {name:"DVD"} --creates DVD in Final Delivery Directory
set subusb to make new folder at finaldel with properties {name:"USB"} --creates USB in Final Delivery Directory
set subweb to make new folder at finaldel with properties {name:"WEB"} --creates WEB in Final Delivery Directory
set subgraphics to make new folder at images with properties {name:"Graphics"} --creates Graphics in Images Directory
set substills to make new folder at images with properties {name:"Stills"} --creates Stills in Graphics Directory
set subcam_1 to make new folder at rawcards with properties {name:"Cam-1"} --creates Cam-1 in RAW Cards Directory
set subcam_2 to make new folder at rawcards with properties {name:"Cam-2"} --creates Cam-2 in RAW Cards Directory
set subcam_3 to make new folder at rawcards with properties {name:"Cam-3"} --creates Cam-3 in RAW Cards Directory
--Moves files from template directory to working directory
set sourceFile to POSIX file "/Users/ricoh-admin/Movies/WeddingTemplate Creator/2005_0001.rtf"
set destFolder to POSIX file "loc & finaldel & subdvd"

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file sourceFile to destFolder
end tell
```

end tell

Any help would be appreciated and to know where I went wrong etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up POSIX paths and HFS paths.

This version creates the entire folder structure in one line via the shell (this requires a slash separated POSIX path)

The Finder duplicates the RTF file which requires colon separated HFS paths.

```
tell application "Finder" to set frontmost to true
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the wedding date" default answer "YYYY/MM/DD") --Asks for date of wedding
set DT to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the couples name" default answer "Bride & Groom + Surname") --Asks for couples name
set Wedding to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the type of day" default answer "Wedding") --Asks for type of day, Wedding, Party, etc
--Creates directory with info from above
set loc to (choose folder "Please choose where you would like to save the files") as text --Loc = Location of where directory will be placed
set newfoldername to JobName & " - " & DT & " - " & Wedding --Adds Date, Couples name and event type to make directory name
set folderStructure to "/{Audio/{Music,RAW\\ Audio\\ Cards},Documents,Exports,FCPX\\ Library,Film\\ Poster,Final\\ Delivery/{DVD,USB,WEB},Images/{Graphics,Stills},RAW\\ Cards/{Cam-1,Cam-2,Cam-3},XML}"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of (loc & newfoldername) & folderStructure

set sourceFile to (path to movies folder as text) & "WeddingTemplate Creator:2005_0001.rtf"
set destFolder to loc & newfoldername & ":Final Delivery:DVD:"
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate file sourceFile to folder destFolder
end tell
```

Comment: That seems to work like a treat and I see you compressed my mess of novice files.

Comment: It's not necessarily a mess when using the Finder. `mkdir` is just another – more powerful – approach.